# forever run sail.js + angularjs project gets Unknown provider: a

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sails.js

I have a sail.js project, I am using angularjs. Whenever I try to run the project, it's working with sails running in development mode like: `sails lift`. But if I run `sails lift --prod` in production mode. I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module cineApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: a
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=a
    at http://localhost:1337/min/production.min.js:3:6452
    at http://localhost:1337/min/production.min.js:3:25864
    at d (http://localhost:1337/min/production.min.js:3:25034)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (http://localhost:1337/min/production.min.js:3:25371)
    at d (http://localhost:1337/min/production.min.js:3:24422)
    at http://localhost:1337/min/production.min.js:3:24546
    at f (http://localhost:1337/min/production.min.js:3:6859)
    at n (http://localhost:1337/min/production.min.js:3:24323)
    at $a (http://localhost:1337/min/production.min.js:3:26013)
    at h (http://localhost:1337/min/production.min.js:3:13536)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=cineApp&p1=Error%3A…tp%3A%2F%2Ffl.limijiaoyin.com%3A1337%2Fmin%2Fproduction.min.js%3A3%3A13536)
```

I defined the angular app in a app.js which located at assets/js/app.js.

```
var cineApp = angular.module('cineApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

So, why angularjs is working when sails running in development mode, but no in production mode.

Comment: can you paste code of how have you defined `cineApp` before minification..?

Comment: @Chandan Please see the updated code.

Comment: please check the answer by @Thomas below. See if that helps..

Answer (score 1):

`a` is probably a minified form of something. This will happen if you minify your code and don't [annotate your injected functions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) properly in one of these two ways:

```
['$http', '$timeout', function($http, $timeout) {
  ...
}]

function myFun($http, $timeout) {
};
myFun.$inject = ['$http', '$timeout'];
```

Comment: Could it be the grunt task problem? Did you notice that the js file is not inserted to the layout.ejs. It seems the grunt task is working using sails lift, but not working with forever.

Comment: It's inserting a reference to `/min/production.min.js`, not inserting the file directly. As is evident from the stack trace, that file has been generated and can be resolved, so this is not your problem.